# Problem symfony 4 routes and apache with docker

Tags: php, mysql, apache, docker, symfony4

I'm trying to create a docker app with Symfony 4, PHP 7.2, MySQL and Apache.
But i have a problem with symfony routes, probably because my apache configuration is wrong.
I have created a TestController with /test route and i have a 404 not found error when trying to go to localhost:8080/test.
But localhost:8080/index.php/test is working.

Thanks.

My docker-compose file :

```
version: "3.7"
services:
        apache:
                container_name: apache
                build: ./docker/apache
                ports:
                        - 8080:80
                depends_on:
                        - php
                        - mysql
                volumes:
                        - .:/var/www/app

        mysql:
                container_name: mysql
                image: mysql
                restart: always
                volumes:
                        - ./docker/data/db:/var/lib/mysql
                command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
                environment:
                        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
                        MYSQL_DATABASE: app
                        MYSQL_USER: khan
                        MYSQL_PASSWORD: khan

        php:
                container_name: php
                build: ./docker/php
                working_dir: /var/www/app
                volumes:
                        - .:/var/www/app
```

My app.conf (Apache):

```
LoadModule deflate_module /usr/local/apache2/modules/mod_deflate.so
LoadModule proxy_module /usr/local/apache2/modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_fcgi_module /usr/local/apache2/modules/mod_proxy_fcgi.so

<VirtualHost *:80>
    # Uncomment the following line to force Apache to pass the Authorization
    # header to PHP: required for "basic_auth" under PHP-FPM and FastCGI
    #
    # SetEnvIfNoCase ^Authorization$ "(.+)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1

    # For Apache 2.4.9 or higher
    # Using SetHandler avoids issues with using ProxyPassMatch in combination
    # with mod_rewrite or mod_autoindex
    #<FilesMatch \.php$>
        #SetHandler proxy:fcgi://php:9000
        # for Unix sockets, Apache 2.4.10 or higher
        # SetHandler proxy:unix:/path/to/fpm.sock|fcgi://dummy
    #</FilesMatch>

    # If you use Apache version below 2.4.9 you must consider update or use this instead
    # ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/var/www/project/public/$1

    # If you run your Symfony application on a subpath of your document root, the
    # regular expression must be changed accordingly:
    # ProxyPassMatch ^/path-to-app/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/var/www/project/public/$1

    ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ fcgi://php:9000/var/www/app/public/$1 

    #<Directory /var/www/app/public>
        #AllowOverride All
        #Require all granted
    #</Directory>

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost.com    
    DocumentRoot /var/www/app/public
    ServerName dev.app.com
    ServerAlias www.dev.app.com
    <Directory /var/www/app/public>
        # enable the .htaccess rewrites
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        #Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    # uncomment the following lines if you install assets as symlinks
    # or run into problems when compiling LESS/Sass/CoffeeScript assets
    # <Directory /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/app/public>
    #     Options FollowSymlinks
    # </Directory>

    #<FilesMatch \.php$>
        #SetHandler proxy:fcgi://php:9000/var/www/app/public/$1
        # for Unix sockets, Apache 2.4.10 or higher
        # SetHandler proxy:unix:/path/to/fpm.sock|fcgi://dummy
    #</FilesMatch>

    ErrorLog /var/log/app_error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/app_access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

My apache Dockerfile:

```
FROM httpd:2.4-alpine
RUN apk update; \
    apk upgrade;
COPY app.conf /usr/local/apache2/conf/app.conf
RUN echo "Include /usr/local/apache2/conf/app.conf" \
    >> /usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf
```

Answer (score 1):

I would like to post how I resolved the problem with the displayed index.php file in the URL.

I just switched on the mod_rewrite option of the Apache and restarted the Apache.

I added the line in the Dockerfile:

```
RUN a2enmod rewrite && service apache2 restart
```

Comment: Heroes don't always wear capes... Thank you SO much !